# Mail crash immediatly after launch

Tags: macos, mail.app, mojave

I've just update MacOS to the latest version of Mojave 10.14.1 from the previous one (already Mojave) and now the Mail app won't load anymore. It crashes instantly after launch, no GUI is visible before the bug

Greetings

Comment: Open the Console app in your Utility folder.  There is a lots going on there. So look at the time when you exactly try to launch Mail. Then copy following 30 lines after that and post in your post.

Comment: Is mail still active just no window?

Comment: Mail is not active, I've got a lot of message in the console If I select error I got this https://pastebin.com/5CjNWwxh

Answer (score 1):

I've booted in recovery mode and reinstall Mojave and now everything works fine again